# Javascript - Adding 1 to a Variable Generates multiple console.log entries

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps API to capture the zoom level when the user clicks on the map. I would then like to increase the zoom level by 1, but I'm having trouble doing this and I'm getting multiple console.log entries when I run this in the browser.

Here's the script in question:

```js
var map = null;

function initialize() {

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    scaleControl: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-28.8413400, 153.4384050),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
    myOptions);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-28.8413400, 153.4384050),
    map: map,
    icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png',
    title: ''
  });

  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.7028557, 153.0120736);
  var icon = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png';
  var marker = createMarker(point, '<p style="font-size:14px">Acme Services 2</p>', icon)

  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(-29.8089498, 152.8230076);
  var icon = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png';
  var marker = createMarker(point, '<p style="font-size:14px">Acme Services 4</p>', icon)

  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(-26.6564235, 153.0586826);
  var icon = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png';
  var marker = createMarker(point, '<p style="font-size:14px">Acme Services 4</p>', icon)



}
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  size: new google.maps.Size(100, 20)
});

function createMarker(latlng, html, icon) {
  var contentString = html;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    icon: icon,
    map: map,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
  });


  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    console.log(zoomLevel);
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    var latitude = event.latLng.lat();
    var longitude = event.latLng.lng();
    var newCentre = latitude + ', ' + longitude;
    var currentZoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    console.log("currentZoomLevel: " + currentZoomLevel);
    var zoomLevel = parseInt(currentZoomLevel, 10) + 1;
    console.log("zoomLevel: " + zoomLevel);
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Google Maps Markers</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.33&key=myKeyHere"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    html,
    body,
    #map-canvas {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

When I look at the console log I can see multiple entries of the following:

> [Log] currentZoomLevel: 12
>   [Log] zoomLevel: 13

It looks like it's generating an entry for each marker that I have on the map. For example if I have 3 markers I'm getting 6 entries in the console.log, but I'm not sure why this is happening?

Comment: Where are you calling this code at? Is it possible you are calling this inside another event listener and thus creating multiple listeners?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Google Maps API, but is it possible you're attaching the event listener multiple times (i.e., script being loaded in multiple places)? One way to debug this is to do a `console.log` in the main body of your script. A demo would also help. **EDIT:** ^ what he said

Comment: perhaps, somehow, the code `google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) { ....})` is executed 284 times ... what they said ^^^ :p

Comment: The [posted code (fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/uaryjscq/)) works fine if I add it to Google's [SImple Map Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @geocodezip thanks I've added the full code for the map, looks like it's logging an entry for each marker that I'm generating.

Comment: @PatrickEvans thanks I think you are right but I'm not 100% certain. Have updated my question to include all the code for the map.

Comment: Of course it does as you are attaching **map** event listeners every time you add a marker.

Comment: @MrUpsidown thanks appreciate if you could show me how to only add a map event listener once.

Comment: Well... just take it out of your `createMarker` function which you are calling every time you create a marker...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply move your `map` event listeners outside of your `createMarker` function.

I also modified:

- declared `infowindow` as a global variable so that it can be accessed in both functions
- merged the 2 map click event listeners into one

```js
var map = null;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    scaleControl: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-28.8413400, 153.4384050),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
    myOptions);

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    size: new google.maps.Size(100, 20)
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    infowindow.close();

    var latitude = event.latLng.lat();
    var longitude = event.latLng.lng();
    var newCentre = latitude + ', ' + longitude;
    var currentZoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    console.log("currentZoomLevel: " + currentZoomLevel);
    var zoomLevel = parseInt(currentZoomLevel, 10) + 1;
    console.log("zoomLevel: " + zoomLevel);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    console.log(zoomLevel);
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-28.8413400, 153.4384050),
    map: map,
    icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png',
    title: ''
  });

  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.7028557, 153.0120736);
  var icon = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png';
  var marker = createMarker(point, '<p style="font-size:14px">Acme Services 2</p>', icon)

  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(-29.8089498, 152.8230076);
  var icon = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png';
  var marker = createMarker(point, '<p style="font-size:14px">Acme Services 4</p>', icon)

  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(-26.6564235, 153.0586826);
  var icon = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png';
  var marker = createMarker(point, '<p style="font-size:14px">Acme Services 4</p>', icon)
}

function createMarker(latlng, html, icon) {

  var contentString = html;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    icon: icon,
    map: map,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```